# Java Regex ? (expr){num} confusion?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to identify strings which contain exactly one integer.
That is *exactly* one string of contiguous digits e.g. "1234" (no dots, no commas).

So I thought this should do it: (This is with the Java String Escapes included):

```
(\\d+){1,}
```

So the "\d+" correctly a string of contiguous digits. (right?)

I included this expression as a sub-expression within "(" and ")" and then I'm trying to say "only one of these sub-expressions.

Here's the result of ( matcher.find() ) of checking various strings: 
(note the regex from now on is'raw' here - NOT Java String Escaped).

```
Pattern:(\d+){1,}
                  Input String                        Result
                             1                          true
                       XX-1234                          true
      do-not-match-no-integers                         false
         do-not-match-1234-567                          true
          do-not-match-123-456                          true
```

It seems the '1' in the pattern is applying to the "+\d" string, rather than the number of those contiguous strings.

Because if I change the number from 1 to 4; I can see the result change to the following:

```
Pattern:(\d+){4,}
                  Input String                        Result
                             1                         false
                       XX-1234                          true
      do-not-match-no-integers                         false
         do-not-match-1234-567                          true
          do-not-match-123-456                         false
```

What am I missing here ?
Out of interest - if I take off the "(" and ")" altogether - I'm getting a different result again

```
Pattern:\d+{4,}
              Input String                        Result
                         1                          true
                   XX-1234                          true
  do-not-match-no-integers                         false
     do-not-match-1234-567                          true
      do-not-match-123-456                          true
```

Comment: `(\d+){4,}` and suchlike mean *match 4 or more consecutive occurrences of 1 or more digits*, and basically, = `\d{4,}`. Probably, you want `^\D*\d+\D*$` => [`s.matches("\\D*\\d+\\D*")`](https://regex101.com/r/rb6PqG/1)

Comment: Or do you need to match a string that only consists of digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regex:

```
^[^\d]*\d+[^\d]*$
```

That's zero or more non digits, followed by a substring of digits and then zero or more non digits again until the end of the string. Here is the java code (with escaped slashes):

```
class MainClass {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex="^[^\\d]*\\d+[^\\d]*$";
        System.out.println("1".matches(regex));  // true
        System.out.println("XX-1234".matches(regex)); // true
        System.out.println("XX-1234-YY".matches(regex)); // true
        System.out.println("do-not-match-no-integers".matches(regex)); // false
        System.out.println("do-not-match-1234-567".matches(regex)); // false
        System.out.println("do-not-match-123-456".matches(regex)); // false
      }         
}
```

Comment: Yup that works for me : I get it : you basically saying "some none-digits (or nothing) + a string of digits(including only 1) +some none digits(or nothing).

Answer (score 3):

`Matcher.find()` will try to find a match inside the String. You should try `Matcher.matches()` instead to see if the pattern fits in all the string.

In this way, the pattern you need is `\d+`

EDIT:
Seems that I misunderstood the question. One way to find if the String has only one integer, using the same pattern is:

```
int matchCounter = 0;
while (Matcher.find() || matchCounter < 2){
   matchCounter++;
}
return matchCounter == 1
```

Comment: yeah but that won't work for XX-1234 for example. HE wants to have just one number inside the string. But the string can consist of more than the number. "XX-1234".matches("\\d+") is false but in the question it should be true

Comment: Updated. The question was a little bit confusing because it wasn't clear (at the moment of answering) which is the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the 'find()' and 'matches()'  - I was undecided which best suited me here as well. (I went with 'matches()' in the end).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RegEx [`^\D*?(\d+)\D*?$`](https://regex101.com/r/nWtHzF/3)

- `^\D*?` makes sure there is no digits between the start of your line and your first group
- `(\d+)` matches your digits
- `\D*?$` makes sure there is no digits between the your first group and the end of your line

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/nWtHzF/3)

So, for your Java String, it would be : `^\\D*?(\\d+)\\D*?$`

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to make sure your regex considers the entire string, using ^ and $.

To do that, you could match zero or more non-digits, followed by 1 or more digits, and then zero or more non-digits.
The following should do the trick:

```
^[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*$
```

Here it is on regex101.com:  https://regex101.com/r/CG0RiL/2

Answer (score -1):

Edit: As pointed out by Veselin Davidov my regex isn't correct.

If i understand you right you want it only to say true when the entire String matches the pattern. yes?

Then you have to call `matcher.matches();`

Also i think your pattern must be just `\d+`.

If you have problem with regex i can recommend you https://regex101.com/ it explains you why it matches something and gives you a quick preview.

I use it every time i have to write regex.

Comment: the problem with just \d+ is that it will match if he has a digit, but it will also match if he has more than one digits

Comment: yes, but if he uses .matches() the regex must match the whole string.

Comment: yeah but that won't work for XX-1234 for example. He wants to have just one number inside the string. But the string can consist of more than the number. "XX-1234".matches("\\d+") is false but in the question it should be true

Comment: Ohh, your right. Looks like i didn't read the question good enough.